# Android Auto DHU : how to change the display size of DHU

Tags: android-auto

Does anyone know whit is going on to the DHU?

The layout suddenly shows only half.

I print out the SurfaceContainer info, width:800, heigh:240.

The original is width:800, heigh:400.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled the related software, but useless.
Finally, Factory reset the smart phone to solved this problem.

It is quite stange, it still happens occasionally.